# Passing variable to Javascript doesn't work in Rails 4.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I have just created a simple Rails 4.2 application to upload file to S3. I'm trying to follow this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails#submitting-and-rendering-the-images and it looks like in javascript `<%= @variable %>` gets parsed as string.

I tried this.

This is what I have in `/users/new`

```
  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: 201, acl: :public_read)
    @user = User.new
  end
```

And this is what I tried in `application.js`

```
window.vaz = <%= @s3_direct_post.url %>;
```

but when I do `console.log(window.vaz);` I get `"<%= @s3_direct_post.url %>"` instead of the real value.

I tried gon as well but gon has a lot of issues with Rails 4.2

I verified that `@s3_direct_post.url` returns something in the console.

Comment: Generally speaking, that `<%= @s3_direct_post.url %>` substitution only happens in an ERB file. This is a good thing - otherwise you'd need to make sure `@s3_direct_post_url` exists for every page on which you use that JavaScript file, and if you're minifying, that's a bit of a problem. The nicer way to get data from your server into your JavaScript is to make AJAX requests against the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .erb extension to application.js file (application.js.erb). `<%= =>` is erb syntax and you need to process it as erb file first so that `<%= @s3_direct_post.url %>` is evaluated as ruby code.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing